# Most "pythonic" way of using if/else statements in try/except blocks?

Tags: python, try-catch

Say I have a function that reads lines in a file and returns a list of strings describing lines not found:

```
def find_fields(file):
file_errors = []
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("Name"):
               name_line = next(f)
               if name_line == "\n":
                   file_errors.append("Name not found in file.")

               if line.startswith("Date"):
                  date_line = next(f)
                  if name_line == "\n":
                      file_errors.append("Date not found in file.")
   return file_errors
```

I want to wrap this in a try/except block where if the list is populated, I raise an exception:

```
def main():
 infile = 'myfile.txt'
 try:
    file_errors = find_fields(infile)
    if file_errors:
       raise ValueError
 except ValueError:
    sys.exit(f"File is missing fields: {file_errors}")
 else: 
    print("File looks good.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is it good practice to use the try/except block this way? As in, try the function (`find_fields`) and if the list exists, to raise an exception within the block, else, print a string and move on?

Should I raising an exception if the list is populated within the function itself?

**Edit:**

```
def find_fields(file):
file_errors = []
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("Name"):
               name_line = next(f)
               if name_line == "\n":
                   file_errors.append("Name not found in file.")

               if line.startswith("Date"):
                  date_line = next(f)
                  if name_line == "\n":
                      file_errors.append("Date not found in file.")
   if file_errors:
       raise ValueError(f"Errors were found {file_errors})"
```

Followed by:

```
try:
   find_fields(file)
except ValueError:
   sys.exit("Missing fields not allowed in file.)
else:
   print("File looks good.")
```

Comment: No, this is a nonsensical use of `try-except`. Wrapping a piece of code that you `raise SomeErrror` in an `if` block just to catch it doesn't make any sense. Just use remove the `try-except` and do `sys.exit(f"File is missing fields: {file_errors}")` in the `if` instead of `raise ValueError`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Questions about programming style are off topic here, as they are subjective.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your feedback. Would it make more sense to raise an exception in after an `if` statement in the function itself then use `try-except` block to catch it? I've added an edit with an example.

Comment: It depends on exactly how you expect to use that function. And that is really up to you. But that would at least make sense